# Going more than recommended Speed in Break-in Period

Tags: engine, motorcycle, yamaha, break-in

I have a new Yamaha motorbike. Seller told me not to ride speed more than 50 Kmph for first 1000KM but I rode it 60 for 10 - 15 minutes due to some reason. How does it affect to my Motorbike ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking in the engine correctly will greatly affect the longevity and performance of the bike, plus you have warranty regards to worry about as well. I found this from a [Yamaha forum](http://www.fz8-forum.com/forum/fz8-general-discussion/631-break.html) and seems along the lines of what I understood to be right:

> According to Yamaha, you are to keep the engine below 5900 rpm for the first 600 miles and vary the rpm. Do not do any steady high rpm rides like on the hwy. After that change the oil and filter and you are good to go. With todays technology in eng building, the engine is broken in after the first 100 miles. I kept my eng below 5900 for the first 100 miles and then varied it at short bursts up to 8000 for the next 200 miles. After that .....redline is the limit.

For best results, you can (at least here in the US) have the motorcycle dealer do the break-in for you. By doing so, you never have to worry about the boring part of owning your bike, that being the break-in period. As well, you know the warranty will be covered without issue.

I cannot tell you if your riding at 60kph for a period of time has done any damage. My gut check would tell me no, but you never know.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about going slightly over the speed. That's still comfortably within the limit of what even the smallest bike can do without putting a lot of stress on the engine.

Answer (score 1):

There's usually two methods people discuss. The 1st method is the one Paulster2 described, which is by the manufacturers suggestion in the manual. The 2nd is a more controversial method of running it hard.

Here's a snippet from [MotoMan][1]:

> The Short Answer: Run it Hard !
>
> Why ??  Nowadays, the piston ring seal is really what the break in
>   process is all about. Contrary to popular belief, piston rings don't
>   seal the combustion pressure by spring tension. Ring tension is
>   necessary only to "scrape" the oil to prevent it from entering the
>   combustion chamber.
>
> If you think about it, the ring exerts maybe 5-10 lbs of spring
>   tension against the cylinder wall ...  How can such a small amount of
>   spring tension seal against thousands of  PSI (Pounds Per Square Inch)
>   of combustion pressure ??  Of course it can't.

I'm not going to recommend which is right, but I'll provide a few more links of the 2nd method so you can read and make your own decision.

http://rideapart.com/2013/10/how-to-break-in-a-new-motorcycle-engine/
http://www.motorcycleextremist.com/Motorcycle-Engine-Break-in-the-Right-Way!.html

Comment: The problem with your second method is that you can invalidate your warranty. While it may or may not work (I've seen a plethora of the "right" way to break-in an engine), the only way I'd choose any other method than the way the manufacturer states, is if I wasn't worried about it in the first place. After that, with everything else, you might as well paste it on a board somewhere and throw darts at it to select. Everyone has an opinion on how to do the break-in. Choose at your own risk.

Comment: @Paulster2 - I agree, choose at your own risk. I usually use the manufacturers recommended method for my cars and trucks which I expect to drive for a lot of miles. I've used the more performance oriented hard break in method on my motorcycles and performance cars which don't expect to see high mileage. Some of the race motors we've built were only quickly broken in on the dyno, but usually these motors are rebuilt or fail from hard usage other than from improper break in and high miles.

Comment: Yup, sounds about right to me. People have the right (since they own it) to break in a vehicle any way they want to. If I build/rebuild an engine, I'd use a whole different break-in strategy since warranty is no issue.